# Creating a method calling an async method, but the calling method isn't async itself, though returning a Task, but how does it work?

Tags: c#

I've watched a video of a person creating a non async method that calls an async method but doesn't use the async/await keywords to do so, and I'm confused.

Here's the code:

1 - This is the async method he created first

```
public async Task SaveData<T>(
        string storedProcedureName,
        T parameters,
        string connectionString = "Default")
    {
        using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(connectionString));

        await connection.ExecuteAsync(
            storedProcedureName,
            parameters,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
```

2 - This is the method calling the above method, without being async

```
public Task InsertUser(UserModel user) =>
        _db.SaveData(storedProcedureName: "dbo.spUser_Insert", new { user.FirstName, user.LastName });
```

I don't understand how you don't need to have the async/await keywords there for the `InsertUser` method knowing that a `Task` should be awaited in order to be used right ?

Comment: Also see: [eliding async and await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a method `async` if you want to use `await` within that method. Your `SaveData` method returns a `Task`. If you want to `await` that method when you call it then you can only do so in a method declared `async`. `await` will wait until the returned `Task` completes and then unwrap it. Your `InsertUser` method is not using `await` so it doesn't need to be `async`. It will just return the `Task` immediately and not wait for it to complete. That means that that `Task` can be waited on further down the call stack or it can just be allowed to carry on in parallel and ignored if there's no need to know when it completes.

Comment: I see, so the the fact that it doesn't need to `await` it in this case is due to the fact that since it's sending a call to a stored procedure it doesn't need to get a value back to be used within that `InsertUser` method therefore it doesn't need to use await right ?

Comment: "it can just be allowed to carry on in parallel" it will not complete normally unless you `await` it. If you want to fire-and-forget, you need an `await` somewhere, usually you do `Task.Run` which will await it for you